# Replace characters in a string loop and function failing

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string stored as a variable randWord.

I'm hiding the randWord with a series of blank spaces using a loop.

```
var tempSpace = '';
for (var i = 0; i < randWordLngth; i++) {
   tempSpace = tempSpace + ' ___ ';
}
```

The user tries to guess the hidden word. The guesses are stored in a string variable called userInput.

I created this function to replace the blank spots with the correct user guessed letter.

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}
```

I need to call the function and print the correctly guessed words at the right index but leave the unguessed words blank. I've tried to institute this with another loop but am getting the syntax wrong.

```
wordPosition = tempSpace.replaceAt(positions, userInput);

if (wordPosition != ' ___ ') {
    for (var i = 0; i < randWordLngth; i++) {
        tempSpace = tempSpace + ' ___ ';
        $('#wordBox').html(wordPosition)
    }
}
```

To discover what index the user guessed character is I created a function

```
function getAllIndexes(word, val) {
    positions = [];
    for(i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if (word[i] === val) {
            positions.push(i);
            console.log("the position of the letter(s) are " + positions);
        }
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
getAllIndexes(randWord, userInput);
```

You can see an example of the failure in the pic. The hidden word is gallery and the user (me) guessed 'l'. It should have printed the character l twice at the 2 and 3rd index.
[image]

Comment: what is `randWordLngth` where is it coming from

Comment: randWordLngth is a global variable that is just saving randWord.length in a new variable.

Comment: Try debugging your code. I think you will find the problem ....

Comment: love to, but they have taught us debugging yet.

Comment: How do you set `positions`?

Comment: Can you post the whole script. It's really hard to tell where all these variables are coming from.

Comment: It's 240 lines of js. Last time I did that someone told me not to, haha. But I did update it to include the functionality of how I was checking the hidden word agaist the user input to find all instances of a character

Comment: `replaceAt()` expects `positions` to be a single integer, but you're setting it to an array.

Comment: You should also learn to use function return values, rather than setting global variables in the function.

Comment: we were instructed to not use return values.

Comment: You are going to have a lot of issues because the spaces you leave have 5 char  " ___ "  and the letter that you replace them with only have 1 char. So the length of the total string will change during the game and you won't know you indexes correctly.

Comment: Yes, @LioraHaydont I know that is also one of the issues. Do you have a suggested fix?

Comment: If you're going to learn, I think you should learn correctly like @Barmar suggested with return values -- before bad habits ensue. And it's probably time to learn to debug as well. It's a vital skill. Rarely will you write code that works perfectly the first time. And you can't expect others to fix your code for you. Just my opinion.

Comment: I agree @MFisherKDX. I'd like to learn how to step through the code and spot these errors especially because I've spent about 3 hours trying to read jquery and javascript docs plus StackOverflow to find a solution. I don't expect a complete fix, but perhaps a more concrete and clear explanation of the issue that I'm overlooking.

Comment: There are actually several issues in your code. I would recommend testing each function by itself before putting them together. For instance, your `replaceAt` function doesn't work correctly. Re-read the `substr` documentation and the arguments it expects.

Comment: replaceAt is looking for two arguments. The first, an integer for the index, and the second, a string and I'm feeding it an array and a string...

Comment: I got it working everyone.